# Scripting language vs XML Driven Engine Comparison

Tags: xml, scripting

We have a group who are using (and wishing to continue to use) a scenario engine (state machine based) for robotics. The development process generates an xml file which is then subsequently run by a player. Intuitively, to me, this feels constrained, but I don't have the programming background to really argue for or against this vs directly using a scripting (or programming) language.

What are other people's thoughts re the two approaches?

Comment: Impossible to answer without a much more detailed understanding of the requirements. Perhaps the existing approach is constrained, but perhaps it does everything that's required of it?